# Wait for method to complete before returning value

Tags: java, android, callback, wait

I've found quite a few answers to similar questions, but have yet to find one that works for me.  I have a method in a helper class that returns a String value of a users present latitude.  here is the code.

```
public String getLatitude(){
    createLocationListener();
    defineCriteria();
    createLocationManager();
    getLocation();
    return String.valueOf(d_latitude);
}
```

My issue is that class variable `d_latitude` is updating correctly in the `getLocation()` or more specifically the `onLocationChanged()` method, but `getLatitude()` is returning a null `d_latitude`  before `getLocation()` is complete.  Like I said, the solutions I have found didn't work for me for whatever reason or they seemed totally too complex for my situation (200 line special classes and such).

```
private void getLocation(){
    //get single shot location update, null looper sets single shot
    locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, locationListener, null);
}


private void createLocationListener(){
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location){
            d_latitude = location.getLatitude();
            Toast.makeText(Location.this, "olc lat= " +d_latitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            stopLocationListener();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You should place some log statements in your code so you can see how your code folows. Which statement is executed first an which last. And think about synchronous/asynchronous.

Comment: @greenapps.  Yes, i do.  that's how i figured out what was going on.  I deleted those lines of code for clarity of the question.

Comment: Not identical, but possibly close enough: [Get the last known location on Android synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903415/get-the-last-known-location-on-android-synchronously)

Comment: Does your ```getLatitude()``` run in the UI thread? If it is you can use a listener to inform the finish of the method, if it is not you can just use ```while (d_latitude == null);``` (This is not a good approach but it does give some ideas).

Comment: Your `getLocation()` method does not get a location. It asks Android to find out the device's location. That happens asynchronously, as it may take some time to find that out. This is perfectly normal.

Get rid of `getLatitude()`. Do whatever work you need to do with the location when the location arrives, in your `onLocationChanged()` method (or things called from there)

If you want to have a `getCachedLatitude()` -- where the calling code can deal with the fact that you do not necessarily have a location yet -- that is perfectly fine.

Comment: For example, see [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.9/Location/Classic), where I kick off a background Retrofit request to obtain a weather forecast when I get the location in `onLocationChanged()`.

Comment: I also recommend you use a broadcast to get the values when available. You can send the broadcast around when you display the Toast and the receiver can then pick it up and complete the task in the receiver.
This however means most of your code then goes into the onReceive method of your receiver implementation

Comment: @CommonsWare  I initially had this code to retrieve Lat and Lon (ironically to make a Retrofit request as well) in my main Activity and did what you suggested -- just wait for it before continuing.  I am attempting to offload some of that code to helper classes and trying to just simply get a return of Lat and Lon.  I seem to be struggling because now my onLocationChanged() is in a helper class and don't know how to wait for it.

Comment: "trying to just simply get a return of Lat and Lon" -- that's not a good plan.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how async functions and listeners work together.

For example, if you changed your method

```
private void getLocation(LocationListener l) {
    locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, l, null);
}
```

Then you could pass in the listener, which calls back to the method, and "waits"  for a response on a different thread.

You could define your own callback interface to get the latitude externally.

An example would be

```
public interface MyLocatonListener {
    void onLatChanged(Latitude lat);
    void onLongChanged(Longitude lng);
}
```

And you pass an instance of that around, but, continuing on without that, since you already have a builtin listener...

Since you're not guaranteed an immediate response, you cannot `return` from this method, so make it void

```
public void getLatitude(){
    defineCriteria();
    createLocationManager();
    getLocation(new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location){
            // latitude is "returned" here 
            d_latitude = location.getLatitude();
            Toast.makeText(Location.this, "olc lat= " +d_latitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
        } 
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
        }
    });
    // d_latitude == null here, most likely 
}
```

For another example, you can extract the `LocationListener` parameter up to the `getLatitude` method, then pass it down into `getLocation`

```
public void getLatitude(LocationListener l){
    defineCriteria();
    createLocationManager();
    getLocation(l);
}
```

By the way, I think you can define criteria and location manager before this method

Comment: How do I return latitude from a void method?

Comment: Like I said, you don't. You notify a calling method via an interface, otherwise refered to as a listener or callback function

Comment: OK, just want to make sure, there wasn't an easy answer before I did that research on callbacks.  Thanks